# Remove path prefix when testing web service

Tags: web-services, rest, oracle-apex

I'm using apex 4.2.6. I have a problem with using REST services. When I try to test out a webservice that I created in apex I get a prefix in URL. That prefix actually messes up the real URL. When I delete that prefix my webservice works.

I'll try to explain it with this picture.

1. The first part of picture shows part in administration where you have to define path prefix for REST services.
2. Second part shows what I get when I go to my service and click button "TEST".
3. Third part shows what I get after I manually delete path prefix that was put there by apex.
   As you can see it works after I delete it.

[image]

Comment: I really don't remember that admin setting from Apex 4.  With ORDS 3, ORDS handles path handling and not Apex.  You define different paths with java -jar ords.war and not in the Apex interface.  Can't you just keep it blank?

Comment: As you can see it's required field. I can't leave it blank :/

Comment: Also I should note that I configured my paths for 3 different databases for 1 ords.

Comment: Is there an option for you to upgrade to apex 5.0 and Ords 3?